# How to hide the ribbon on the sharepoint modal box , also the scrollers are not working

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Modal Dialog Options

```
function Myfunction() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var options = {
        url: clientContext.get_url() + "/_layouts/Page1.aspx",
        showMaximized: true,  

        //width: 950,  
        //height: 1000,  
        dialogReturnValueCallback: myCallback
    };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    return false;
}

function myCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) {
}
```

I am trying to hide the ribbon which is coming on the modal box .. I have the added the below css on Page1.aspx

```
<style type="text/css">  
.s4-notdlg
{
   display:none;
}
```

It hides only the Site Actions part and the logged in name of the user. I still have the black thick image of the ribbon on my page. I want the complete ribbon to be hidden. Also, the scroll bars appear on the page, but they do not scroll completely to the bottom of the page.

Some one please help me.

Comment: What is under `"/_layouts/Page1.aspx"`? The modal dialog box does not have a ribbon per se. It only is a box (with a blue top bar containing the close and maximize button) loading something else via IFRAME - no ribbon there ;-) Of course there is a ribbon on the original page you are opening the modal dialog from, but thats hidden behind the modal window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
body{overflow:auto !important;}
#s4-leftpanel { display: none;}
.s4-ca {margin-left:0px !important;}
#s4-ribbonrow{height:auto !important;min-height:0px !important;}
#s4-ribboncont{display:none;}
#s4-titlerow{ display:none;}
.s4-ba {width:100%; min-height:0px !important;}
#s4-workspace{float:left;width:100%; overflow:auto  !important;}
body #MSO_ContentTable{min-height:0px !important;position:inherit;}
```

Use above css in your page1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In sharepoint 2013 the following CSS worked for me:

```
.ms-dialog #s4-ribbonrow { 
    display: none;
}
```